# Spring Integration WS || How can be create xsd files and wsdl files for spring integration ws service

Tags: spring-integration

I am new with spring integration ws and now as per of project requirement, I have to generate the xsd/wsdl file to provide the vendor for the services that were created in spring integration ws. I have read spring integration ws manual where I have impression that we have to first generate the xsd manually and then with the help of these xsd we have to generate the wsdl file.

So I just want to confirm if this is the only process to manually generate the xsd file for the spring integration ws service or do we have any option to automatically generate the wsdl and xsd file for my services already written using spring integration ws.

Please consult me with your view/input/suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, no. Spring Integration WS module is fully based on the [Spring-WS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) project, which general concept is **Contract First**.

First of all you should go to the Spring-WS Docs to understand how the server (inbound) part should be built.

Comment: Thanks Artem. So that means I have to first generate xsd and then wsdl and then develop my service class. So do have only option to generate xsd and wsdl manually or do we have any tool to help me to generate xsd and wsdl for my requirement. Please suggest.

Comment: No. There is just enough to Model classes with JaxB annotations and run the appropriate tool from your IDE to generate XSDs. The Spring WS generates WSDL dinamically on request to your application. Please, read Spring WS docs. For the Spring Integration you should take a look into samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ws-inbound-gateway